# Unknown URL content://

Tags: java, android

Here is my code:

```
public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri() {

        //CODE - MDC
        ContextWrapper myCW = new ContextWrapper(myContext);
        ContentResolver resolver = myCW.getContentResolver();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "name");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);


        Uri uri = null;

        uri = Uri.parse("content://" + "data/data/com.555.number/shared_prefs/IMG.jpg");

        try {
            uri = resolver.insert(uri, contentValues);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            String msg = ex.getMessage();
        }



        return uri;
    }
```

Every time I run this code I get the error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://data/data/com.ebs.ecount/shared_prefs/IMG.jpg.  Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: Do you need a leading `/` before the first `data` (i.e. `/data/data...`)?

Comment: Don't make up a Uri to something that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `ContentProvider` registered in your device (or probably any device) that has an authority of `data`.